# Is React Native good for cross-platform Machine Learning apps built with TensorFlow.js?

Tags: react-native, tensorflow, machine-learning, tfjs-node

With the release of `tfjs-react-native` and the ample support for the platform, is React Native stable and reliable enough for a startup to go all-in on to build cross-platform Machine Learning apps?

Note: We are building a Health-Tech app that uses dietary and physiological data to recommend exercise plans and meal options for optimal health. The most resource-intensive task the app would likely perform is to use `open-pose` like models to improve exercise posture.

From AirBnB's blog, they moved away from React Native because they had to maintain 3 different codebases as they had started with native development. We are just about starting and have experience with React but are open to considering others like Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking two different questions, you can use `tensorflow-js` in any js framework. If you want my opinion: go with React, there's simply more documentation on using `tensorflow` with React, and you already have experience with it. Just don't start developing three different codebases, that's not a matter of React/TF vs Flutter/TF, it's a matter of organisation.